# Android DDMS not working

Tags: android, ddms

The allocation tracker in DDMS in eclipse is no longer working. It worked last night, but my phone got a android update this morning. It no longer will work. When I click the Get Allocations button the console displays as follows:

```
[2014-07-21 17:42:31 - ddm-heap] *** Received REAL
```

in red text. Any one else have this problem?

Comment: Try disabling and reenabling usb debugging mode on your phone, they rsa key may have changed with an update

Comment: @dave Didn't work. I even deleted eclipse and downloaded the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that my code was breaking ddms. Go figure.

Comment: How was your code breaking ddms? Sounds strange since your code has  nothing to do with ddms. Can you elaborate further please because I have the exact same issue.